# How to run joomla in docker with mysql in windows

Tags: mysql, docker, joomla

I want to run joomla in docker but failed to do as joomla container is exited and logs show the some warning as:-The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in /makedb.php on line 20

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in /makedb.php on line 20

MySQL Connection Error: (2054) The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Answer (score 1):

this error occurs to the incompatible version of MySQL with Joomla as we pull latest images. So we should pull the MySQL image of version 5.X and latest Joomla image.
The problem can easily be solved with this.
run this command in docker

```
    docker run --name joomla_db -p 3306:3306 -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test mysql:5.7
    docker run --name joomlaweb --link joomla_db:mysql -p 8080:80 -d joomla
```